# How to graph sequence ranges, for example intron sequences or conserved domains

Tags: sequence

I am a bioinformatics beginner.
I want to draw line graphs such that for a gene, say gene_A, intronic regions are (20,100), (500,600) and a conserved domain was found in (400-550), then I should get base position/sequence length on the x axis and gene name on the y axis.
Is there any software that can help me do this?

I used matplotlib but would like better visuals, any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!
[image: Sample result from Matplotlib]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. What will your input be? What exactly are you trying to graph? You say "gene name on the y axis" but show an example with fractional numbers instead. You say "base position/sequence length on the x axis" but those two are very different things. You say you have an intron from position 500 to 600 but then have a conserved domain at 400-550, so _part_ of the intron. None of this makes much sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: Would ggbio do the trick?